# QT Creator, Сигналы и слоты

Tags: qt, сигналы-слоты, creator

```
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGridLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) //window::connect
{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
     QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("1");
     QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("2");
     QPushButton *button3 = new QPushButton("3");
     QPushButton *button4 = new QPushButton("4");
     QPushButton *button5 = new QPushButton("5");
     QPushButton *button6 = new QPushButton("6");
     QPushButton *button7 = new QPushButton("7");
     QPushButton *button8 = new QPushButton("8");
     QPushButton *button9 = new QPushButton("9");

     QWidget *window = new QWidget;
     QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
     QInputDialog *pq=new QInputDialog;
     layout->addWidget(pq);
     layout->addWidget(button1);
     layout->addWidget(button2);
     layout->addWidget(button3);
     layout->addWidget(button4);
     layout->addWidget(button5);
     layout->addWidget(button6);
     layout->addWidget(button7);
     layout->addWidget(button8);
     layout->addWidget(button9);

     QObject :: connect (button1,SIGNAL(clicked()), button1,SLOT(showMenu ()));



     window->setLayout(layout);
          window->show();

    return app.exec();
```

Comment: что за глупая реализация? Надо все по классам разбивать

Comment: @Данил наверно, это просто тестовый код для изучения поведения классов Qt

Comment: Кстати есть какие-либо ошибки и прочее? И уберите картинку и вставьте код.

Comment: Вообще ошибок много, но сам виджет запускается

Comment: @Razor0109 может все работает, просто нет всплывающего меню? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#showMenu

Comment: @Razor0109 вот с таким кодом все работает QObject :: connect (button1,SIGNAL(clicked()), window,SLOT(close()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему код рабочий, просто не установлено [меню](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#menu)

Попробуйте так:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QAbstractButton>
#include <QMenu>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
        QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("1");
        QMenu menu("menu");
        menu.addAction("one");
        menu.addAction("two");
        button1->setMenu(&menu);
        QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("2");
        QPushButton *button3 = new QPushButton("3");
        QPushButton *button4 = new QPushButton("4");
        QPushButton *button5 = new QPushButton("5");
        QPushButton *button6 = new QPushButton("6");
        QPushButton *button7 = new QPushButton("7");
        QPushButton *button8 = new QPushButton("8");
        QPushButton *button9 = new QPushButton("9");

        QWidget *window = new QWidget;
        QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
        QInputDialog *pq=new QInputDialog;
        layout->addWidget(pq);
        layout->addWidget(button1);
        layout->addWidget(button2);
        layout->addWidget(button3);
        layout->addWidget(button4);
        layout->addWidget(button5);
        layout->addWidget(button6);
        layout->addWidget(button7);
        layout->addWidget(button8);
        layout->addWidget(button9);

        QObject :: connect (button2,SIGNAL(clicked()), button1,SLOT(showMenu()));

        window->setLayout(layout);
             window->show();

       return app.exec();
}
```

P.S. 
Надо сказать что для показа меню не нужны слоты и сигналы

Comment: Насчёт меню окей, а если допустим хочу уничтожить эту же кнопку" [virtual]QPushButton :: ~ QPushButton ()", тоже ничего не происходит

Comment: @Razor0109 если вам надо посмотреть как работает сигнал, я сделал так, что при нажатии второй кнопки открывается меню первой кнопки.

Comment: по поводу удаления: buttonX->deleteLater(). https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater